# Ajax request doesn't success with JSON

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.ajax({        
    //check all selections are made
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkin_process.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,                                    
    sucsess: function(){
        // alert(data.success);
        alert("sucess");
        $("#message").fadeOut(5000);  
    },
    statusCode: {            
        406: function() {                
            alert("sucess");
        },            
        409: function() {                
            alert("err");
        }            
    }
});
```

As in this code the ajax request returns only the error not the success.

But in `json` file it returns the json encoded data properly. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You have written `sucsess` wrong, it should be `success`

Comment: @jeroen: OMG!!! wasted lot of time thx :)